# Why does `assign_attributes` nullify nested fields not contained in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Title says it: When using `assign_attributes` for a nested model, it seems to nullify previously set fields of the nested model, even if they're not contained in the params assigned.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end

e = Employee.new
e.build_person
e.person.kind = :employee

e.assign_attributes(person_attributes: { name: 'John Doe' })

e.person.attributes
# {"id"=>nil, "kind"=>nil, "name"=>"John Doe"}
```

For structural reasons, `build_person` and assigning the `kind` should happen before the `assign_attributes` call, so just setting it afterwards is not an option.

Is this a bug, and is there a way of working around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use

```
e.assign_attributes { ... }, update_only: true
```